# Push Notification from API Update?

Tags: push-notification, rss, apple-push-notifications, soundcloud

I am working with the soundcloud API and I want to send a user a push Notification on iOS whenever a targeted user uploads a new track. The app is developed with the Ionic Framework/ Cordova. I've looked into Amazon SNS and Parse but I can't find a way to watch the array. I can also do this through a RSS feed if that is easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RSS is probably a pretty good way to detect new episodes/sounds posted. Hopefully, Soundcloud will [implement PubSubHubbub](http://blog.superfeedr.com/howto-pubsubhubbub/), or you'll have to fetch/parse the feeds yourself.
Once you've identified the new entries, you can then sent the notifications.

Comment: So would detecting a change with a node server be the best way to do it?